# _context.savechanges() not working asp.net core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

In the following code

```cs
BorrowHistoryTracking = await _context.BorrowHistoryTrackings.FindAsync(id);
            BorrowHistoryTracking.ReturnDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
            await _context.AddAsync(BorrowHistoryTracking);

            _context.Entry(BorrowHistoryTracking).State = EntityState.Modified;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I can see that `BorrowHistoryTracking.ReturnDate = DateTime.Today.Date;` correctly modifies the property `ReturnDate` .
But adding the modified object to the context and setting the state to modified somehow does not work.

After `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` the property `ReturnDate` is not modified.

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Here the `BorrowHistoryTracking` class

```cs
public class BorrowHistoryTracking
{
    public int BorrowHistoryTrackingId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Book")]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public Book Book { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Customer")]
    public int LibraryCustomerTrackingId { get; set; }

    public LibraryCustomerTracking LibraryCustomerTracking { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Borrow Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BorrowDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Return Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? ReturnDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(24)")]
    [Display(Name = "Borrowing Options")]
    public string BorrowingOptions { get; set; }
}
```

And here my context class

```cs
public FilippaLibraryContext (DbContextOptions<FilippaLibraryContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public DbSet<LibraryCustomer> LibraryCustomers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<BorrowHistory> BorrowHistories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<BorrowHistoryTracking> BorrowHistoryTrackings { get; set; }

    public DbSet<LibraryCustomerTracking> LibraryCustomerTrackings { get; set; }
}
```

In the table `BorrowHistoryTracking` I want to keep tracks of the books borrowing. It is a kind of duplicate of `BorrowHistory`, but contains also the past bookings. `BorrowHistory` contains only what is booked, withou keeping trace of the past events.

The action method is

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        BorrowHistory = await _context.BorrowHistories.FindAsync(id);
        LibraryCustomer = await _context.LibraryCustomers.FindAsync(BorrowHistory.LibraryCustomerId);

        BorrowHistoryTracking = await _context.BorrowHistoryTrackings.FindAsync(id);
        LibraryCustomerTracking = await _context.LibraryCustomerTrackings.FindAsync(BorrowHistoryTracking.LibraryCustomerTrackingId);

        if (BorrowHistory != null)
        {
            _context.BorrowHistories.Remove(BorrowHistory);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        if (LibraryCustomer != null)
        {
            _context.LibraryCustomers.Remove(LibraryCustomer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }


        if (BorrowHistoryTracking != null)
        {
            var BorrowHistoryTracking = await _context.BorrowHistoryTrackings.FindAsync(id);

            BorrowHistoryTracking.ReturnDate = DateTime.Today.Date;

            _context.Entry(BorrowHistoryTracking).State = EntityState.Modified;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        if (LibraryCustomerTracking != null)
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("../Books/Index");
    }
```

This method deletes the booking in the `BorrowHistory` table, but should keeps trace of the booking in the `BorrowHistoryTracking` table

**2nd UPDATE**

```cs
namespace Library.Pages.BorrowHistories
{
public class DeleteModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly FilippaLibraryContext _context;

    public DeleteModel(FilippaLibraryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public BorrowHistory BorrowHistory { get; set; }


    [BindProperty]
    public LibraryCustomer LibraryCustomer { get; set; }





    public BorrowHistoryTracking BorrowHistoryTracking { get; set; }
    public LibraryCustomerTracking LibraryCustomerTracking { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        BorrowHistory = await _context.BorrowHistories
            .Include(b => b.Book)
            .Include(b => b.LibraryCustomer).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BorrowHistoryId == id);

        BorrowHistoryTracking = await _context.BorrowHistoryTrackings
            .Include(b => b.Book)
            .Include(b => b.LibraryCustomerTracking).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BorrowHistoryTrackingId == id);

        if (BorrowHistory == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        BorrowHistory = await _context.BorrowHistories.FindAsync(id);
        LibraryCustomer = await _context.LibraryCustomers.FindAsync(BorrowHistory.LibraryCustomerId);

        BorrowHistoryTracking = await _context.BorrowHistoryTrackings.FindAsync(id);
        LibraryCustomerTracking = await _context.LibraryCustomerTrackings.FindAsync(BorrowHistoryTracking.LibraryCustomerTrackingId);

        if (BorrowHistory != null)
        {
            _context.BorrowHistories.Remove(BorrowHistory);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        if (LibraryCustomer != null)
        {
            _context.LibraryCustomers.Remove(LibraryCustomer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }


        if (BorrowHistoryTracking != null)
        {
            var BorrowHistoryTracking = await _context.BorrowHistoryTrackings.FindAsync(id);

            BorrowHistoryTracking.ReturnDate = DateTime.Today.Date;

            _context.Entry(BorrowHistoryTracking).State = EntityState.Modified;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        if (LibraryCustomerTracking != null)
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("../Books/Index");
    }
}
}
```

And here the `BorrowHistory` class

```cs
public class BorrowHistory
{
    public int BorrowHistoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Book")]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public Book Book { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Customer")]
    public int LibraryCustomerId { get; set; }

    public LibraryCustomer LibraryCustomer { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Borrow Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BorrowDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Return Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? ReturnDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(24)")]
    [Display(Name = "Borrowing Options")]
    public string BorrowingOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your code? Do you want to add a new `BorrowHistoryTracking` to the database? You're doing two contradictory things: add and mark as modified.

Comment: Hi Gert, I'm trying to modify a field.

Comment: So what's the purpose of `await _context.AddAsync(BorrowHistoryTracking);`?

Comment: I have removed it from the code, but my code does not work. The modification of ReturnDate is not reflected in the context

Comment: You better show the code of the `BorrowHistoryTracking` class and mapping code, if present.

Comment: This question needs more details and clarity. You have to post full code

Comment: just posted more code

Comment: We need the whole action code.

Comment: the whole action has been posted

Comment: I am sorry but I can't see where you declare BorrowHistoryTracking ?

Comment: Sergey, here it is

Comment: I see you use the same Id to find BorrowHistory and BorrowHistoryTracking. How it is possible? Could you post BorrowHistory class too?

Comment: both classes are very similar

Comment: Yes but the same data will have different Ids

Comment: It works as designed:

Comment: borrowHistoryTracking.Book = borrowHistory.Book;
            borrowHistoryTracking.BookId = borrowHistory.BookId;
            borrowHistoryTracking.BorrowDate = borrowHistory.BorrowDate;

            borrowHistoryTracking.ReturnDate = borrowHistory.ReturnDate;
            borrowHistoryTracking.BorrowingOptions = borrowHistory.BorrowingOptions;

Comment: when the user borrows a book, both tables are updated

Comment: and the the context is saved

Comment: _context.BorrowHistories.Add(BorrowHistory);
_context.BorrowHistoryTrackings.Add(borrowHistoryTracking);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I've found a solution.

I've reseeded my database tables using `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', RESEED, 1)`

In this way Imade sure that the IDs of the `BorrowHistory` and `BorrowHistoryTracking` tables are the same.

Pointing to the same row, the following code will do the job and set the `ReturnDate` to the right value:

```
BorrowHistoryTracking.ReturnDate = DateTime.Today.Date;

_context.Attach(BorrowHistoryTracking).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug. Remove _context.AddAsync and add  EntityState.Modified

```
var  existingTracking = await _context.BorrowHistoryTrackings.FindAsync(id);
//or if existingTracking ==null try this
var  existingTracking = await 
_context.BorrowHistoryTrackings.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i=> i.Id==id);

 if (existingTracking != null)
{
 existingTracking.ReturnDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
 _context.Entry(existingTracking).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
else  .... return errror
```

Update

I can see from your update that  you are trying to use the same id  for to find BorrowHistory and BorrowHistoryTracking. IMHO this is a bug too.  You have to find by id something one. After this you maybe should use BookId ( or something similar) to find another record.

```
var bookId  BorrowHistoryTracking.BookId;
var  existingTracking = await 
_context.BorrowHistoryTrackings.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i=> i.BookId==bookId);
.... and so on
```

Comment: Hello Sergey, Igave it a try, but it does not work

Comment: Did you check if borrowHistoryTracking != null?